# Emacs: dbus-related error when trying to switch to latex mode

Tags: emacs, dbus, auctex

since I began using dbus with Emacs some days ago (meaning I recompiled with dbus-support), when I open a latex-file or try to switch manually to latex-mode, I get

```
File mode specification error: (invalid-function dbus-ignore-errors)
```

and emacs stops there remaining in fundamental mode.

I use dbus for Zeitgeist-Support and that works fine and up to the recompilation, Auctex worked equally fine. I checked if the dbus-functions are available with the result: They show up in the help (including "dbus-ignore-errors") but they don't seem to be available for execute-extended-commad (M-x) meaning they don't show up in completion and cannot be executed. On the other hand they are available for lisp-eval.

I don't know if that's normal behavior for these functions, but anyway there seems to be some sort of a problem with the availability of the functions for auctex?

The situation does not change by disabling the zeitgeist-plugin.

Any suggestions?

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: Type `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, reproduce the problem, and then post the stacktrace so somebody may have better chances t help

Comment: Maybe you provide an example how you run into this, starting with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: It seems like the error occurs in a byte-compiled Emacs Lisp file, that was compiled without knowing that `dbus-ignore-errors` is a macro. Find what that file is using the stacktrace, and recompile it after loading the `dbus` module.

Comment: @legoscia - YES! You got it! I needed simply to reinstall auctex. Sorry I didn't think of it. It was byte-compiled and didn't know about the dbus support. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error `invalid-function` usually means that a piece of Emacs Lisp code was compiled before a certain macro was defined, and is now trying to call that macro as a function.  To solve this, find the module in question and recompile it after making sure that the macro (`dbus-ignore-errors` in this case) is defined.

---

In the case of Auctex, this happens because `tex.el` contains the following:

```
;; Require dbus at compile time to prevent errors due to `dbus-ignore-errors'
;; not being defined.
(eval-when-compile (and (featurep 'dbusbind)
            (require 'dbus nil :no-error)))
```

That is, it tries to load the dbus library, but ignores failures. If the Emacs under which Auctex is being compiled doesn't support dbus, `dbus-ignore-errors` will thus be compiled into a function call when compiling `tex.el`.  That's no problem, because the `dbus-ignore-errors` call is protected by a `featurep` test.

If this byte-compiled file is then loaded into an Emacs instance that *does* support dbus, we suddenly reach the line in question, and try to call the macro as a function, which fails with `invalid-function`.  That's why the file needs to be recompiled before being loaded into a dbus-enabled Emacs.

One way to solve this is to wrap the `dbus-ignore-errors` line into `eval`, changing this line:

```
     (dbus-ignore-errors (dbus-get-unique-name :session))
```

to this:

```
     (eval '(dbus-ignore-errors (dbus-get-unique-name :session)))
```

That would postpone the decision on how to evaluate that expression until runtime, when Emacs will know that `dbus-ignore-errors` is a macro.

Comment: In my case, it was something in the auctex-package so reinstallation of the package was sufficient. Thanks!